# Print array key value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which i get like this:

```
$tet = $SimplicateApi->makeApiCall('GET','/crm/person?q[first_name]=Kevin1');
```

I wanted to see all the array keys inside the array so i did

```
print_r(array_keys($tet['data']['0']));
```

The Results:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => id 
    [1] => interests 
    [2] => simplicate_url 
    [3] => avatar 
    [4] => linked_as_contact_to_organization 
    [5] => gender 
    [6] => first_name 
    [7] => family_name 
    [8] => full_name 
    [9] => email 
    [10] => phone 
)
```

My question is how do i check whats inside in for example `first_name`

Comment: `print_r($tet['data']['0']['first_name']);`?

Comment: Check the edit for your question. You can see that there is not `first_name [7]`. You array has they key `6` and it's value is `first_name` (7 is the `family_name`).

Comment: Thanks @RuslanOsmanov this worked, what does the ['0'] do ?

Comment: @Kevin.a, this is the way to access an array item at index zero. In this case `$tet['data']` is the array.

Comment: awesome @RuslanOsmanov thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array_keys($array)` returns an array of `$array` keys.

---

Since the result of `array_keys($tet['data']['0'])` contains `first_name`, we can access the value with the `[]` operator as follows:

```
print_r($tet['data']['0']['first_name']);
```

In this code we access `$tet['data']['0']` *array* by `'first_name'` key.

Answer (score 1):

`var_dump` full array and see all keys and their values in one shot:

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($tet['data']['0']);
echo '</pre>';
```

To have more insight, `var_dump` original array to get full info about it:

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($tet);
echo '</pre>';
```

So that you may know why you have to use `data` key and the `0` key.
`<pre>` tag is just used to have nice output.

*I hope it helps*